# How do you rebuild a rust wasm application after changes?

Tags: rust, wasm-pack

I'm using wasm pack to build a web app from rust. I went through docs for getting started and was able to build the application with `npm init wasm-app dirname` and run it in the browser. However, when I change and build the rust code the changes aren't reflected in the app being served. Is there a standard way to re-build (maybe even automate re-building) the rust app and the app built by `npm init wasm-app` command?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up missing a step. I needed to add

```
{
   app_name: "file:../pkg",
   ...  
}
```

to the dependencies in package.json

now `wasm-pack build` updates the app as expected